# Why wouldn't my sieve terminate when I rewrote it as a foldl?

Tags: haskell, primes, lazy-evaluation, sieve

What's the specific problem with my `foldl` that prevents it from terminating or producing output?

First I achieved a sieve for primes. It's not the best, but it works just fine as (for example) `take 20 primesA`.

```
primesA :: [Integer]
primesA = sieve 2 []

sieve :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
sieve i []   = (i:) $ sieve (i + 1) $ map (*i) [i ..]
sieve i composites@(h : t)
  | i == h    =     sieve (i + 1) t
  | otherwise = (i:) $ sieve (i + 1) $ unionIncreasing composites $ map (*i) [i ..]

unionIncreasing :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
unionIncreasing [] b = b
unionIncreasing a [] = a
unionIncreasing a@(ah:at) b@(bh:bt) | ah <  bh  = ah : at `unionIncreasing` b
                                    | ah == bh  = ah : at `unionIncreasing` bt
                                    | otherwise = bh : a  `unionIncreasing` bt
```

Then I thought it would be more Haskell-y to eliminate the counter `i` using `foldl` as follows. But this is not effective.

```
primesB :: [Integer]
primesB = [2..] `differenceIncreasing` composites

composites :: [Integer]
composites = foldl f [] [2..]
  where f [] i = map (*i) [i ..]
        f knownComposites@(h:t) i | i == h    = knownComposites
                                  | otherwise = (h:) $ unionIncreasing t $ map (*i) [i ..]

differenceIncreasing :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
differenceIncreasing [] b = []
differenceIncreasing a [] = a
differenceIncreasing (x:xs) (y:ys) | x <  y    = x : xs `differenceIncreasing` (y:ys)
                                   | x == y    = xs `differenceIncreasing` ys
                                   | otherwise = (x:xs) `differenceIncreasing` ys
```

It neither terminates nor produces any output when I run (for example) `head primesB`.

Presumably ghci is looking at the infinitely many lists of multiples of primes in its vain attempt to attain the value of the head of the list.

But why specifically does it do that?

Comment: sacundim's answer answers your specific question, but you might want to have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/nisstyre56/4699275 and the paper http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: @Wes - aha, thank you! Page 11 of M. O'Neill's paper shows exactly the sieve that I was aiming for. I had spent a little more time trying to achieve that myself, but it wasn't so easy for me. Now I can study it carefully.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`foldl` can't ever terminate on an infinite list.  This is the definition of the function:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f z [] = z
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

Notice that in Haskell, when you force a thunk, evaluation only stops when we reach a step where the outermost operation is a data constructor (well, unless you use explicit forcing or lazy pattern matching).  In the case of `foldl`, that can only be when it hits `[]`.  Let's look at this example, reversing an infinite list (which should give it away already):

```
foldl (flip (:)) [] [1..]
  = foldl (flip (:)) [1] [2..]
  = foldl (flip (:)) [2, 1] [3..]
  = foldl (flip (:)) [3, 2, 1] [4..]
  = foldl (flip (:)) [4, 3, 2, 1] [5..]
  .
  .
  .
```

Since `foldl` will always be the outermost operator, and `foldl` is not a constructor, it will never terminate.  With some reflection you can see that no left fold of an infinite list can ever terminate.

`foldr` doesn't have that problem because its second equation has `f` at the top:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

Example:

```
foldr (:) [] [1..]
  = 1 : foldr (:) [] [2..]
```

Now `(:)` is the outermost operator, so evaluation stops here; something has to force the constructor's arguments for evaluation to continue.

Comment: Oh! Looking back at section "Only folds and horses" in learnyouahaskell.com I see that it's pointed out quite explicitly but I didn't absorb it: "One big difference is that right folds work on infinite lists, whereas left ones don't! To put it plainly, if you take an infinite list at some point and you fold it up from the right, you'll eventually reach the beginning of the list. However, if you take an infinite list at a point and you try to fold it up from the left, you'll never reach an end!" The next time, I can look up a relevant function like `foldl` at Hoogle and read the source. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(clarification: this repeats more or less closely the last part of [my answer to your question on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/17787/10479) and elaborates on it a bit; I'm not sure if it's a good fit there or not.)</sub>

Your *first version* is actually very close to Richard Bird's solution (from page 11 of M. O'Neill's paper). You can get there not by trial and error, but by code transformation and stepwise improvement.

After some renaming, pre-calculating the first step gives us this very nice-looking code:

```
--     map (*i) [i ..] == map (*i) [i, i+1 ..] == [i*i, i*i+i ..]
--     sieve 2 [] where sieve i [] = (i:) $
--               sieve (i + 1) [i*i, i*i+i ..] == 2 : sieve 3 [4, 6 ..]

primesA :: [Integer]
primesA = 2 : sieve 3 [4, 6 ..]

sieve p cs@(c : t)
   | p == c    =     sieve (p + 1) t
   | otherwise = p : sieve (p + 1) (unionI cs [p*p, p*p+p ..])

unionI a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys) | x <  y    = x : xs `unionI` b
                         | x == y    = x : xs `unionI` ys
                         | otherwise = y : a  `unionI` ys
```

There are two problems with this code. There is the **`(...(((a+b)+c)+d)+...)`** calculation structure, which puts the more frequently-producing streams lower in the structure than the less frequently-producing ones.

But the more immediate concern is the premature handling of each prime's multiples. E.g. when you reach 5, `[25, 30 ..]` is added into the composites. But that should only be done when 25 is reached. Doing so would radically reduce the total number of multiples streams being processed at each moment (from `Θ(n)` to `Θ(sqrt(n/log n))`, for *n*-th prime). This has very significant impact on efficiency.

We can explicitly synchronize on squares of primes, taken from the primes sequence itself as it is being produced (this just maintains a separate back-pointer `ps` into the sequence, which is advanced at much slower pace than the production point):

```
primesAC = [2,3] ++ sieve 4 (tail primesAC) 9 [4,6..]

sieve k ps@(p:pt) q cs@(c:ct)                 -- candidate "k", prime "p"
  | k == c  =     sieve (k + 1) ps q ct       -- square "q", composite "c"
  | k < q   = k : sieve (k + 1) ps q cs
  | otherwise =   sieve k       pt (head pt^2)       -- k == q == p*p
                        (unionI cs [q, q+p ..])
```

This is now just half a step away from Richard Bird's solution, which fixes *both* problems with one cleverly used `foldr`, creating the **`a+(b+(c+(...)))`** calculation structure where each new prime's multiples stream starts from the prime's square anyway and the synchronization is implicit in the data:

```
primesAD = (2 :) . sieve 3 . 
            foldr (\p r-> p*p : unionI [p*p+p, p*p+2*p ..] r) [] $ primesAD

sieve p cs@(c : t)                  -- == diffI [p..] cs, if p<=c
  | p == c    =     sieve (p + 1) t
  | otherwise = p : sieve (p + 1) cs
```

Each prime's square is produced first unconditionally, to prevent the run-away access prematurely forcing further parts of data.

So `foldr`, and not `foldl`, is a natural fit to this problem.

---

You 2nd variant is

```
primesB :: [Integer]
primesB = [2..] `diffI` composites

composites = foldl f [4,6..] [3..]
  where 
        f cs@(h:t) i | i == h    = cs    
                     | otherwise = h : unionI t [i*i, i*i+i ..]

diffI (x:xs) (y:ys) | x <  y    = x : xs `diffI` (y:ys)
                    | x == y    =     xs `diffI` ys
                    | otherwise = (x:xs) `diffI` ys
```

This evidently intends to compute `composites` by similar iterative addition of each number's multiples into the mix; trouble is, `foldl` doesn't let us in into its internal computation process which is never *quite* finished (as other answers already pointed out). `foldl` is unrelenting like that. :) We could turn it into a *productive* `iterate`-based iteration, but the same problems of premature addition and the inverted structure will remain. Plus it now adds multiples of *all numbers*, not just of primes as before:

```
composites = foldl f [4,6..] [3..]
 -- no part of calculation of (f [4,6..] 3) is forced here, but if it were, ...
 = foldl f (f [4,6..] 3) [4..]                  
 = foldl f (4:unionI [6,8..] [9,12..]) [4..]    
 = foldl f (4:unionI [6,8..] [9,12..]) [5..]
 = foldl f (4:union (unionI [6,8..] [9,12..]) [25,30..]) [6..]
 = foldl f (4:union (union (unionI [6,8..] [9,12..]) [25,30..]) [36,42..]) [7..]
 = ....
```

And  `` ([2..] `diffI`) `` is the same as `sieve 2` above, so *that* adds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may wonder how to correct my code `primesB`, the following revision will work. It will "interleave the individual heads properly" as Klaus Draeger wrote [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17481) in cstheory.se. It's equivalent to, though maybe less pleasing than, the code attributed to Richard Bird on page 11 of M.E. O'Neill *The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes*: http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf (thanks @Wes) in print as: http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0956796808007004

```
primesB :: [Integer]
-- #1 necessary change
-- primesB = [2..] `differenceIncreasing` composites
primesB = 2 : [3..] `differenceIncreasing` composites

-- #2 necessary change, entire function
composites = foldr f [] primesB -- not foldl, not [2..]
  where f :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
        -- no destructuring of knownComposites;
        -- square the first list element and don't put that in unionIncreasing's second argument
        f i knownComposites = ((i*i):) $ unionIncreasing knownComposites $ map (*i) [(i+1)..]

-- No change needed in `unionIncreasing` and `differenceIncreasing`.
```

I'm still not certain how a person achieves this solution, unless it's only by trial and error.

Comment: check out [my answer to your question on CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/17787/10479). :)